# InInterceptors annotation does not work in WL

Tags: maven, weblogic, cxf, jax-ws

I have the code below:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "ServicioHTTP")
@Stateless
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "ws.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor")

public class ServicioHTTP {


    @WebMethod(operationName = "serviceAuthHTTP")
    public String serviceAuthHTTP(@WebParam(name = "input") String input) {

            return input;
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is an authentication using HTTP, but it does not work the service always return the input, the InInterceptors is not firing and I dont kno why, I'm deploying in a Weblogic Server

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is `ws.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor` name of a class or a bean? `@InInterceptors` takes names of classes as an argument. CXF handles creation of interceptor objects for you.

Comment: It's the name of a Class:

public class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor extends SoapHeaderInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {...}
}